# Magento sync stock levels with in store till

Tags: magento

I'm writing a script that copies the stock levels found on my server to a local database with have instore which our tills read off.

Trouble is we have over 4000 products, so copying stock levels several times a minute seems rather resource intensive.

I was thinking of modifying magento so that every time stock levels changed on magento it would log the change in a seperate table, then my local script can read off only the changes rather than the whole table.

Is there a function magento uses for making stock changes?  I could then add my code to be called everytime stock levels change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe the event `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before`. Also read [how to observe an event](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm a bit of a noob.  I can't seem to get it working.  It seems I have to create a module first then I can put an 'observer' in it which should hopefully run any time stock level is changed.  However nothing happens.  Here's my code so far.

Create a module:

Directory structure: /app/etc/modules/lucas_all.xml

`code`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<lucas_stocksync>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</lucas_stocksync>
</modules>
</config>
`code`

Comment: /app/code/local/lucas/stocksync/etc/config.xml
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<lucas_stocksync>
<version>0.1.0</version>
</lucas_stocksync>
</modules>
<global>
  <events>
     <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before>
         <observers>
             <lucas_stocksync>
                <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>lucas_stocksync/observer</class>                    <method>cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before</method>
              </lucas_stocksync>
        </observers>
      </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before>       
  </events>
</global>
</config>
`

Comment: /app/code/local/lucas/stocksync/etc/Observer.php

`<?php

class lucas_stocksync_Model_Observer
{
    public function cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before($observer)
    {
  echo "wohoo";
  
    }
 
}

?>`

Comment: To test I go into the backend of magento, go to a random item and change stock level and hope that 'wohoo' appears somewhere on the page, it doesn't.

I think I'm being a dumbass, but I can't figure it out.  Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need also a `<models><lucas_stocksync><class>lucas_stocksync</class></lucas_stocksync></model>` entry so that it can look up the model.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the response.  I'm a little confused about the syntax of 'lucas_stocksync'.  lucas is my namespace and stocksync is my model.  I've used lucas_stocksync and sometimes just stocksync in my code, but I don't really have an understanding where each should be used.  Would you be kind enough to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Normally you should use upper case first letters in the words of your class names. So you class is Lucas_Stocksync_Model_Observer. Now the line config (I made a mistake above) <models><lucas_stocksync><class>Lucas_Stocksync_Model</class></lucas_stocksync></mode‌​l> maps the model code `lucas_stocksync` to the first part of your class name. When you say getModel('yourcode/yourname') it will map it to the class name specified in the class tag + _ + yourname. I suggest you have a look at a basic extending-magento tutorial :)

Comment: I seem to be getting somewhere now.  Though would I be right in saying cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before is depreciated in 1.6 this blog post seems to think so [http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-finding-events-or-where-has-cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before-gone/]

Comment: Now that I have that down, how can I get a hold of both the sku and stocklevel of the product that was just saved?  Sorry about all the questions.  Merry xmas btw (if you celebrate xmas).

Comment: Have a look at the data that is passed to your event observer (the first parameter). Just make a var_dump and you will find the modified object some where.